# Text Scaling on Mobile

Tags: android, html, css

I'm building a mobile version of my website, and it's pretty much perfect, except for the email links on the About Us page aren't the right size. I have all my text set to be 14pt, but the text in the links looks more like it's about 4pt. Another thing I've noticed though is that if I turn my tablet to landscape orientation, the font gets bigger, but still not quite as big as it should be. And this only happens in Chrome too. The links look fine in the stock browser. I've tried just about everything I can think of to fix it, but nothing's changed yet. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my CSS if you need it:

```
.email {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #555;
    border-left: 10px solid #1e9cd7;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #e7e7e7;

    -ms-transition: all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
    -o-transition: all .25s linear;
}

.email:hover {
    background-color: #1e9cd7;
    border-left: 10px solid #e7e7e7;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Comment: Please define "mobile version of your site." and is there any specific reason you are using `pt` as opposed to `em` or `px` etc? - and give us your meta-viewport tag so we know what the browser is doing to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the mobile browser is just scaling things in a way you didn't intend. CSS is pretty specific. If you aren't setting the font size to change with @media rules at specific breakpoints, its just going to be 14pt and your browser is just zooming in or out by default and making them appear smaller. But they are 14pt, unless otherwise declared.

Check out this resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag